# ridge regression phony data R discrepancy

Tags: r

According to my research you can simulate a Ridge Regression by adding "phony data" to the end of a normal OLS regression.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137057/phoney-data-and-ridge-regression-are-the-same
^ One of many examples of places that corroborate this notion.

However in R I fail to replicate the results.

```
> test_0

12    34    24    64   746    24    23    42     7     8     3     4    45   675     3     4    34    43  56   674     3     4    54    34    23    34   435    56    56   234   657    89   980     8    76    65 45564    67    76   789

> test_1

34    24    64   746    24    23    42     7     8     3     4    45   675     3     4    34    43    56 674     3     4    54    34    23    34   435    56    56   234   657    89   980     8    76    65 45564  67    76   789     6


> test_2

24    64   746    24    23    42     7     8     3     4    45   675     3     4    34    43    56   674 3     4    54    34    23    34   435    56    56   234  657    89   980     8    76    65 45564    67 76   789     6     5
```

My three variables. I then append 2 new rows (for the number of independent vars). To test_0 I append two zeros. To test_1 I append a sqrt(.5) and 0. To test_2 I append a 0 and sqrt(.5)

```
> a = c(test_0,0,0)
> 
> b = c(test_1,(sqrt(.5)),0)
> 
> c = c(test_2,0,(sqrt(.5)))
>
```

Then I run two models. lm and lm.ridge

```
>reg = lm(a~b+c)
>
>ridge = lm.ridge(test_0~test_1+test_2, lambda = .5)
>
> reg
>
>Call:
>lm(formula = a ~ b + c)
>
>Coefficients:
>(Intercept)            b            c  
> 1305.42310     -0.02926     -0.02862  

> ridge
>
 >                    test_1        test_2 
>1374.16801379   -0.03059968   -0.02996396
```

The coefficients are different but they should be the same. Why is this the case?
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `a`, `b`, and `c` for the ridge regression, since those have the added numbers?

Comment: According to my knowledge no. The ridge regression function has an additional penalty factor lambda*Beta_vector. OLS lacks this factor.

To account for it, you add the rows to a OLS, which should equal the ridge regression results on the original "un_phonied" data.

Comment: This is not the correct forum in which to get corrections to your misconceptions about statistical methods. Try asking at CrossValidated.com

Answer (score 1):

The reason why my betas were not lining up with the proper Ridge Regression method is that a ridge regression also centralizes (standardizes) the data in the y vector and X matrix before solving for the betas. 
If you centralize the data and then do an OLS with the "phoney" data you get the correct answer.